# Axon 4 - Saga run again after JVM restart

Tags: axon

I am using Axon4 with Spring boot. Created simple saga. Its works well during JVM in flight. However once it restarts, it re-runs the Saga again.

Tried to to JpaSagaStore for persistance, did not work. Below are code snippet. Please help.

```
@Configuration
public class AxonConfig {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public SagaStore sagaStore() {
        return JpaSagaStore.builder().entityManagerProvider(new SimpleEntityManagerProvider(entityManager)).build();
    }
}    

@Saga(sagaStore = "sagaStore")
@Slf4j
public class OrderSaga {

    @Autowired
    private transient CommandGateway commandGateway;

    private UUID orderId;

    private boolean passed;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "orderId")
    public void on(OrderPlacedEvt evt) {
        log.debug("handling {}", evt);
        if (!passed) {
            orderId = evt.getOrderId();
            UUID shipmentId = UUID.randomUUID();
            associateWith("shipmentId", shipmentId.toString());
            commandGateway.send(new PrepareShipmentCmd(shipmentId, evt.getDestination()));
        }
    }


    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "shipmentId")
    public void on(ShipmentPreparedEvt evt) {
        log.debug("handling {}", evt);
        log.debug("orderId: {}", orderId);
        commandGateway.send(new RegisterShipmentForOrderPreparedCmd(orderId, evt.getShipmentId()));
    }

    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "shipmentId")
    @EndSaga
    public void on(ShipmentArrivedEvt evt) {
        log.debug("handling {}", evt);
        log.debug("orderId: {}", orderId);
        commandGateway.send(new RegisterShipmentForOrderArrivedCmd(orderId, evt.getShipmentId()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What database do you use? How did you configure it? Do you use AxonServer to persist your events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution to Prashant his issue was further discussed [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/983#issuecomment-459967742)

In short, the database was set to `create` on each start up.
Due to this, the tokens (for the Tracking Event Processor) which kept track how far the Saga was with handling events were reset on each start up of the application.

Hence switching the line `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` to `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` resolved the issue.

Comment: Great to hear this resolved your problem Prashant! :-)

Comment: It was a mistake under my nose ;) thank you for help !!